# Trouble Understanding Elementary Functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here's an other question that I am having trouble with.

A box with an open top is to be constructed from a rectangular
piece of cardboard with dimensions 12 in. by 20 in. By cutting
out equal squares of side at each corner and then folding up
the sides as in the figure. How do I express the volume $V$ of the box as a
function of $x$.
[image]

Comment: You should be able to see that the height of the box is $x$. The width of the box is 20-?... And the depth is 12-?...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well what's the formula for the volume $V$? It's length times width times height. Now the height in your question is $x$, the length is $20 - 2x$.

Can you guess what the width is and do it from here?

Comment: wait a minute.You say length  = $20 - 2x$.The reason being we are cutting off $x$,how come it's $20 - 2x$ and not $20 - x$?

Comment: @alok: That's because you're cutting of $x$ once on each side, so in total you cut it off twice.

Comment: To be fully correct you should also include the upper and lower bounds on the possible values of x.

Answer (score 2):

Well, google gives me the following [link.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080906095336AAdaVy7)

Comment: Oh it's the same question!